# Errors on running Hyperledger-Explorer test

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am currently having trouble running hyperledger explorer on a basic first network, after setting up postgresql with ./createdb.sh and running ./main.sh install with no problems, I happen to stuck at ./main.sh test command showing errors as such:

PS : I also edited the explorerconfig.json as shown below, and I had also made some few changes at postgrespgtest.js also shown below.

```
explorerconfig.json

{
    "persistence": "postgreSQL",
    "platforms": ["fabric"],
    "postgreSQL": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "5432",
        "database": "fabricexplorer",
        "username": "postgres",
        "passwd": "1234"
    },
    "sync": {
        "type": "local",
        "platform": "fabric",
        "blocksSyncTime": "1"
    },
    "jwt": {
        "secret": "a secret phrase!!",
        "expiresIn": "2h"
    }
}
```

With the :

```
postgrespgtest.js
...
const options = {
    testdb: 'pgtestdb',
    messages: false,
    connection: {
        host: pgconfig.host,
        port: pgconfig.port,
        user: 'postgres',
        password: '1234'
    }
};
...
```

With error message :

```
# Test Results
ok 1 DROP USER IF EXISTS testuser;
not ok 2 WITH PASSWORD 'password';
---
operator: fail
at: <anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/postgrespgtest.js:2:5157)
stack: |-
  Error: WITH PASSWORD '1234';
      at Test.assert [as _assert] (/home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:226:54)
      at Test.bound [as _assert] (/home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:77:32)
      at Test.fail (/home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:319:10)
      at Test.bound [as fail] (/home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:77:32)
      at /home/ec2-user/blockchain-explorer/app/test/postgrespgtest.js:2:5157
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)


 ...(many more errors)
```

Does anybody know what might have caused the problem?
P.S : if there isn't enough resource please do comment i will try my best to give you

Answer (score 0):

Try to cleaning , rebuild once again and do the test .

```
./main.sh clean
./main.sh install
./main.sh test
```

If still ,let me know.